# Tensorflow Cloud ML Object Detection - Errors with Distributed Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to follow Tensorflow's Object Detection tutorial for [distributed training](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md) my own model but am using the code exactly as is from [the repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).

I've made a couple changes from the tutorial, notably to use runtime 1.5 instead of 1.2 as said in the tutorial. There aren't any explicit errors (that I can see) when I try running on Google Cloud ML, but the task quickly exits without training.

Here's the command I use to start the training job:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training object_detection_`date +%s`
    --job-dir=gs://test-bucket/training/
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz
    --module-name object_detection.train
    --region us-central1
    --config ./config.yaml
    --
    --train_dir=gs://test-bucket/data/
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://test-bucket/configs/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```

And this is my config.yaml:

```
trainingInput:
  runtimeVersion: "1.5"
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: complex_model_l
  workerCount: 9
  workerType: standard_gpu
  parameterServerCount: 3
  parameterServerType: large_model
```

And finally the logs from my job finishing up:

```
I  worker-replica-6 Clean up finished.  worker-replica-6
I  worker-replica-7 Signal 15 (SIGTERM) was caught. Terminated by service. This is normal behavior.  worker-replica-7
I  worker-replica-7 Module completed; cleaning up.  worker-replica-7
I  worker-replica-7 Clean up finished.  worker-replica-7
I  worker-replica-8 Signal 15 (SIGTERM) was caught. Terminated by service. This is normal behavior.  worker-replica-8
I  worker-replica-8 Module completed; cleaning up.  worker-replica-8
I  worker-replica-8 Clean up finished.  worker-replica-8
I  worker-replica-1 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-1
I  worker-replica-1 Signal 15 (SIGTERM) was caught. Terminated by service. This is normal behavior.  worker-replica-1
I  worker-replica-1 Module completed; cleaning up.  worker-replica-1
I  worker-replica-1 Clean up finished.  worker-replica-1
I  worker-replica-7 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-7
I  worker-replica-8 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-8
I  worker-replica-6 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-6
I  worker-replica-3 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-3
I  worker-replica-0 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-0
I  worker-replica-2 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-2
I  worker-replica-5 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-5
I  worker-replica-1 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-1
I  worker-replica-7 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-7
I  worker-replica-8 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-8
I  worker-replica-6 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-6
I  worker-replica-3 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-3
I  worker-replica-0 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-0
I  worker-replica-2 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-2
I  worker-replica-5 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-5
I  worker-replica-1 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-1
I  worker-replica-7 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-7
I  worker-replica-8 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-8
I  worker-replica-6 CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:master/replica:0/task:0  worker-replica-6
I  Finished tearing down TensorFlow. 
I  Job failed.
```

As I mentioned, I haven't been able to get something useful from the logs. A bit further up I get this error `Master init: Unavailable: Stream removed` but am unsure how to handle this. Thanks for any push in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue. I fixed it following this:

> roysheffi commented on this issue 3 months ago. Hi @pkulzc, I think I
>   may have a lead:
>
> On line 357, object_detection/trainer.py calls
>   tf.contrib.slim.learning.train() which uses the **deprecated**
>   tf.train.Supervisor and **should be migrated to**
>   tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession instead, as documented in
>   tf.train.Supervisor
>
> This is already requested in tensorflow/tensorflow#15793 and is
>   reported as a solution to tensorflow/tensorflow#17852 on the last
>   comment of yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark#245. [[1](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/56376593-tensorflow-python-framework-errors_impl-unavailableerror-os-error)]

So, in the end, I did this inside trainer.py:

- Put `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(` instead of `slim.learning.train(`